# Getting TypeError: cannot call getNumber method of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

I am working on a simple blackjack program. I am completely new to javascript and am having trouble debugging my program. I keep getting the TypeError: cannot call getNumber method of undefined..... and i'm totally lost. I am trying to get the numerical value stored for each card but it appears thats the error is happening in my `printHand()` method inside the `Hand` class. When printing out the hand of two or more cards, I loop through each card in the hand calling `cards[i].getNumber()` where `cards[]` is the array of cards in each hand. Am i not referencing cards[] properly? I double checked to make sure my methods and variables were set to public but I still cannot figure out why `getNumber()` is being called on an undefined object. Is there something wrong with the way I am referencing this object?

Here is my code:

```
 // Card Constructor
function Card (suit, number){
var the_suit = suit;
var the_number = number;

this.getNumber = function(){
    return the_number;
};
this.getSuit = function(){
    return the_suit;    
};
this.getValue = function (){
    // face cards
    if(the_number > 10){
        return 10;

    // aces
    } else if (the_number < 2){
        return 11;

    // other cards
    } else {
        return the_number;
    }   
};
}

function deal (){
// get card suit
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random ( ) * 4 + 1);
// get car number
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random ( ) * 13 + 1);

var newCard = new Card(rand1, rand2);
}

function Hand (){
// create two cards for initial hand
var card1 = deal();
var card2 = deal();
// store cards in array
var cards = [card1,card2];

// getter
this.getHand = function (){
    return cards;
};

// get the score
this.score = function(){
    var length = cards.length;
    var score = 0;
    var numAces = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if (cards[i].getValue() === 11 ){
    numAces++;
    }   
        score += cards[i].getValue();   
    }
    while(score > 21 && numAces !== 0){
        sum -= 10;
        numAces--;
    }
};
this.printHand = function(){
    var length = cards.length;

    for(i=0; i< length; i++){
    var string = string + cards[i].getNumber() + " of suit " + cards[i].getSuit() + ", ";
    }
    return string;
};

this.hitMe = function(){
    var newCard = deal();
    cards.push(newCard);

}
}

function playAsDealer(){
var newHand = new Hand();
while(newHand.score < 17){
    newHand.hitMe();
}
return newHand;
}

function playAsUser(){
var newHand = new Hand();
var choice = confirm("Current hand: "+ newHand.printHand() + ": Hold (Ok) or Stand(Cancel)");
while(choice){
    newHand.hitMe();
    choice = confirm("Current hand: "+ newHand.printHand() + ": Hold (Ok) or Stand(Cancel)");

}
}

function declareWinner(user, dealer){

//user wins case
if (user.score > dealer.score){
console.log("You are the Champion!");
}

// tie game
else if(user.score===dealer.score){
    console.log("Tied!");
}

else{
    console.log("Loser!!");
}

}


function playGame (){
var user = playAsUser();
var dealer = playAsDealer();
console.log("User's Hand: " + user.printHand());
console.log("Dealer's Hand: " + dealer.printHand());
declareWinner();
}


playGame();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the card object in the function "deal":
should be:

```
function deal (){
   // get card suit
 var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random ( ) * 4 + 1);
        // get car number
 var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random ( ) * 13 + 1);

 var newCard = new Card(rand1, rand2);

 return newCard;
}
```

Comment: same goes for "playAsUser" and sending variables to declareWinner(user,dealer);

Answer (score 1):

There are a few probs, but to get you started:

The error i got was "TypeError: cards[i] is undefined". Since you are calling your deal() function like this:

```
var card1 = deal();
```

You'll need to return the card in the deal func, so change

```
var newCard = new Card(rand1, rand2);
```

to

```
return new Card(rand1, rand2);
```

You'll also need to convert : cards[i].getNumber() to a string when you print the hand

Comment: thank you.... i tried the string idea but it didnt seem to make a difference either way...